# Uninstalling node.js v0.13.0-pre

Tags: node.js

I've installed node js v0.13.0-pre in my ubuntu. 
I need to uninstall it.Uninstalling pre versions needs it's sources but i can't find it in the internet. it seems removed by node team.

Where is v0.13.0-pre repository url?

Comment: `0.13` is the [current version](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_version.h#L25-L27) in the project's [`master` branch](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master).

Comment: On my hostmonster account I installed node src from  http://github.com/joyent/node.git awhile ago, the version was 0.11.8.   Today I did a pull and a build and now it reports v0.13.0-pre

Answer (score -1):

Try install Node.JS using Chris Lea's ppa: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/chris_lea_nodejs